# Corda Finance database table migration failure upgrading from Corda 3 to Corda 4

Tags: corda

When upgrading my database from Corda 3 to Corda 4 I ran into the following error with a table from the Corda Finance :

```
net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CouldNotCreateDataSourceException: Could not create the DataSource: Migration failed for change set migration/cash-schema-v1.changelog-master.sql::initial_schema_for_CashSchemaV1::R3.Corda.Generated:
   Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "contract_cash_states" already exists [Failed SQL: create table contract_cash_states (
    output_index int4 not null,
    transaction_id varchar(64) not null,
    ccy_code varchar(3),
    issuer_key_hash varchar(130),
    issuer_ref bytea,
    owner_name varchar(255),
    pennies int8,
    primary key (output_index, transaction_id)
  )]
```

The table already exists and Corda is trying to create it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corda Finance 3.3 did not include the migration scripts necessary for a liquibase upgrade. Running this migration script to add the migration to the liquibase tables tells Corda that the table has already been created.

```
INSERT INTO <database>.databasechangelog 
(ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) 
VALUES ('initial_schema_for_CashSchemaV1', 'R3.Corda.Generated', 'migration/cash-schema-v1.changelog-master.sql', NOW(), 103, '7:0d961b1ab64deec263ba638e609357d0', 'sql', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.5.4', '2774745582');
INSERT INTO <database>.databasechangelog 
(ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) 
VALUES ('initial_schema_for_CommercialPaperSchemaV1', 'R3.Corda.Generated', 'migration/commercial-paper-schema-v1.changelog-master.sql', NOW(), 98, '7:ee782f59d8cd3b74c7b26f5cfcba3fdd', 'sql', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.5.4', '2774745582’);
```